# Keep multiple trials for each patient in analysis, or average across trials?

Tags: mean, degrees-of-freedom

I have a sample of 10. Each patient completes a walking task twice. Is it reasonable to use both trials in my analysis? I get scale data. I see the patients at two different time points.

To clarify. Each patient performs a walking task twice on one visit. The technology I employ to extract the gait data only gives me averages fro each task. So I have two averages for each patient at each visit. My question is can I use both averages from these trials in my analysis? Or do I have to take an average across the two trials?

I would like to explore the difference between the two time points.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably can't make any powerful conclusions with 5 patients/10 observations. That said, it depends what kind of analysis you are doing. Generally in any classical statistical context, observations need to be independent unless you introduce new parameters to account for the subject/repeated effect.

Comment: I should clarify. I have 10 patients, each completes a walking task twice. Therefore I have 20 observations. These walking tasks were conducted before surgery and then 6 months post-surgery. I was using paired t-tests for analysis to see if there was a change between the two time points.

Comment: In this case you could take the difference of the dependent variable and do a t test for mean=0. This way the observations would be independent because they are all different individuals. Low p values would suggest there is an effect from the surgery.

Comment: A paired t-test is equivalent to taking differences and doing a one-sample t-test vs 0. @Greydon, good that you clarify, but better to put that information into the question by editing it. From what I understand, using a paired t-test is exactly the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: I updated my question. It is regarding using both trials in my analysis or averaging the two trials together. In the first case I would have 2 data points for each patient, but averaging I would have only 1. Which is the proper way?

Comment: @Greydon, what you are (still) not saying in your question is that you are interested "to see if there was a change between the two time points". I don't see how you could do that if you average across the time points. You can do that however using a paired t-test, as you did.

Comment: My apologies, yes comparing between two time points. I would like to know if my treatment intervention has an effect.

Comment: Just just make sure you use a PAIRED 2 sample t test.

Comment: @Sean S: can you also update your answer?